# Apache camel Endpoint schemes duplication

Tags: apache-camel, integration

in apache camel, we have endpoints associated with scheme strings like "cxf", "ahc", "http" and the likes. What happens if there are two components built using the same scheme? I don't see a validation from camel framework which prevents the deployment of components with duplicate schemes. Should there be a validation in the first place or this is by design?

Regards
Gopal

I have a need to re-use available camel components from the community but change the endpoint scheme to make it unique. For example I want to use amqp component but in my blueprint route i would like to have unique scheme used "<camel from uri="mydomain-amqp">. This way I can re-use the amqp as a new component but also keep others using the amqp as is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Camel prevents adding a component using a name/scheme that already exists. Adding your component under a different name would be something like this:

```
getContext().addComponent("mydomain-amqp", new AMQPComponent());
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy thanks for responding. I dont think camel prevents. There is no exception or errror from camel when I try deploying the component. I tested  using Apache karaf.

Comment: @Gopal https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/2589086ba6a76083ffc95790621277f45078e7a2/core/camel-base-engine/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/engine/AbstractCamelContext.java#L583-L585